# como tener un espacio vacio (sin el link) entre dos botones

Tags: html, css

En el siguiente código tengo tres botones con `links` a diferentes páginas, el problema es que entre los botones no deja de estar el link, yo necesito que el `link` sólo se muestre cuando paso el puntero por los botones y no por fuera de estos:

```html
            <div class="row mb-3" >
                <div class ="col d-flex justify-content-center"  type="button" routerLink="/registro-diario" >
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="/assets/img/btn-submenu-regAct/1reg-diario.png" alt="MDB Logo"
                        loading="lazy" width="100" />
                </div>
                <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center"  type="button" routerLink="/novedades-form"  >
                    <img class="img-fluid d-flex align-items-center " src="/assets/img/btn-submenu-regAct/2novedades.png" alt="MDB Logo"
                        loading="lazy" width="100" />
                </div>
                <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center"  type="button" routerLink="/dist-horaria" >
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="/assets/img/btn-submenu-regAct/3distib-horaria.png" alt="MDB Logo"
                        loading="lazy" width="100" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row fuente fs-5">
                <div class="col d-flex  justify-content-center" >
                    <div >Registro Diario</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center" >
                    <div >Novedades</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center" >
                    <div class="text-center" >Distribucion horaria</div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Pongo captura de pantalla de lo que no quiero que pase, pero no sé como solucionar:

[image: imagen del problema]

Perdón por la improligidad de la imagen, si hago una captura de pantalla no toma el puntero.

Comment: El problema es que tu elemento de columna es a la vez un botón. Debes o bien encerrar la imagen dentro de su propio botón y centrarlo en la columna.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Semánticamente hablando, una imagen no debería ser usada como un botón.

Una forma de resolver el problema es envolver la imagen en un botón o incluso en un elemento tipo `anchor`.

Por ejemplo, usando un botón como envoltorio de la imagen, (realmente estamos usando una imagen dentro del botón):

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row mb-3" >
    <div class ="col d-flex justify-content-center">
      <button type="button" routerLink="/registro-diario" class="btn btn-link" width="100" aria-label="MDB Logo">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="/assets/img/btn-submenu-regAct/1reg-diario.png" alt="MDB Logo" loading="lazy" width="100" />
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
      <button  type="button" routerLink="/novedades-form" class="btn btn-link" width="100" aria-label="MDB Logo">
        <img class="img-fluid d-flex align-items-center " src="https://placehold.co/100" alt="MDB Logo" loading="lazy" width="100" />
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
      <button type="button" routerLink="/dist-horaria" class="btn btn-link" width="100" aria-label="MDB Logo">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="/assets/img/btn-submenu-regAct/3distib-horaria.png" alt="MDB Logo" loading="lazy" width="100" />
      </button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row fuente fs-5">
    <div class="col d-flex  justify-content-center" >
        <div >Registro Diario</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center" >
        <div >Novedades</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center" >
        <div class="text-center" >Distribucion horaria</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

La razón es muy simple: hay navegadores de solo texto y podrían simplemente ignorar cualquier imagen, por lo cual la funcionalidad de "botón" no estaría presente, dejando la navegación rota.

Es por ello que usamos el atributo [`aria-label`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-label) para indicar el propósito del botón. En este caso he usado el texto "MDB Logo", pero deberías usar un valor más adecuado, como por ejemplo: "registro-diario", "novedades" y "dist-horaria".

Answer (score 1):

Facil, las propiedades **type="button" routerLink="/tuRuta"** ponlas en las imágenes y no en el div contenedor de las imagenes.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row mb-3" >
                <div class ="col d-flex justify-content-center" >
                    <img class="img-fluid" type="button" routerLink="/registro-diario" src="https://pngimg.com/uploads/buttons/buttons_PNG1.png" alt="MDB Logo"
                        loading="lazy" width="100" />
                </div>
                <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center" >
                    <img class="img-fluid d-flex align-items-center " type="button" routerLink="/novedades-form" src="https://pngimg.com/uploads/buttons/buttons_PNG20.png" alt="MDB Logo"
                        loading="lazy" width="100" />
                </div>
                <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center" >
                    <img class="img-fluid" type="button" routerLink="/dist-horaria" src="https://pngimg.com/uploads/buttons/buttons_PNG148.png" alt="MDB Logo"
                        loading="lazy" width="100" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row fuente fs-5">
                <div class="col d-flex  justify-content-center" >
                    <div >Registro Diario</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center" >
                    <div >Novedades</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center" >
                    <div class="text-center" >Distribucion horaria</div>
                </div>
            </div>
```